# Is it Possible to Insert Row by Row from a Java PreparedStatement?

Tags: java, exception, prepared-statement

I have an application where I am writing batches of 1000 rows to a SQL Server database using a prepared statement. Now if any of these inserts fails, I want to be able to write the offending line to a log file, so that the data is not completely lost. I would prefer if possible to only write the one line that failed to the log, rather than all 1000 lines, so my question is this:

If one line fails while inserting into the table, say a Primary Key violation occurs, is the whole batch prevented from inserting, or only the one row that failed? If the batch fails, is it possible for me to do some sort of loop on the prepared statement, executing each query one by one, and in that way I can figure out the line that failed, and log only that line? Or is the only way for me to achieve this to keep a separate array of each insert statement, and loop through that if the batch happens to fail?

Some more details:

> Database Type: SQL Server 2008
>   Connection Library: java.sql
>   SQL Statement:

```
Insert into Table(Column1,Column2) Values (Value1, Value2)
```

Java Code:

```
PreparedStatement prpStmt = dbConnection.prepareStatement(insertQuery.toString());  
for (List lst : listOfValues){
    prpStmt.setString(1,lst[0]);  
    prpStmt.setString(2,lst[1]);  
    prpStmt.addBatch();  
    dbCount++;  
    if (dbCount == DB_COUNT_LIMIT){  
        try {
            prpStmt.executeBatch();
            dbConnection.commit();  
            dbCount = 0;  
            prpStmt.clearBatch();
        } catch (Exception e){
            for (PreparedStatement ps : prpStmt.getBatches()){
            if (!logToDBIndividually())
                logToFile();
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Do you have an idea of how many total records will be processed during any given time?

Comment: This depends on a number of factors, among them the database involved, the database configuration, the JDBC driver and its configuration, the JDBC connection configuration, the SQL from which you have prepared your statement, and the Java code by which you perform the work.  How about naming the DB and presenting at least model Java code representative SQL?

Comment: The concept of batch will not help if the execution style is statement by statement. In case of batch, the statements are pushed together. You may execute the statements from a list to get this done.

Comment: @john-bollinger Added some edits to show the code I hope to achieve and DB details. blahfunk The records could be in the tens of thousands. james-jithin yes, I know that. The idea is that I will ideally execute a large batch to save time. However if something fails I would move to statement by statement in order to find the specific statement that is failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If one line fails while inserting into the table, say a Primary Key violation occurs, is the whole batch prevented from inserting, or only the one row that failed?

Statements that were executed prior to the one where an error occurred were still executed.  Statements later in the batch may or may not have been executed, at the driver's discretion.  Supposing that you have turned off autocommit for the statement's connection, as you should do when using `executeBatch()` and as it appears you have done, whether to commit or roll back the changes that were successfully made is at your discretion.

Whether or not the driver continues past a failed statement, if one *does* fail then you can determine which of the batched statements were executed successfully by examining the array returned by the `getUpdateCounts()` method of the resulting `BatchUpdateException`.  Refer to that's method's documentation or to the documentation of `Statement.executeBatch()` for details.

Do note also that the example code you present is seriously flawed.  In the event that one of your updates fails, such that an exception is thrown, it is important to either commit or roll back the transaction, and to clear any batched statements that you do not want to re-execute in the next iteration of your loop.  Also, it is rarely appropriate to catch plain `Exception`, and it is especially inappropriate here, given that you want to handle `BatchUpdateException` differently than other exceptions.  Something like this might be better:

```
PreparedStatement prpStmt = dbConnection.prepareStatement(insertQuery.toString());  
for (List lst : listOfValues){
    prpStmt.setString(1,lst[0]);  
    prpStmt.setString(2,lst[1]);  
    prpStmt.addBatch();  
    dbCount++;  
    if (dbCount >= DB_COUNT_LIMIT) {  // should not be >, but no harm in being safe
        try {
            prpStmt.executeBatch();
            dbConnection.commit();  
            dbCount = 0;  
            prpStmt.clearBatch();
        } catch (BatchUpdateException bue){
            int[] updateCounts = bue.getUpdateCounts();

            if (updateCounts.length < dbCount) {
                /*
                 * The first updateCounts.length statements (only) were
                 * executed successfully.  The next one failed, and no more
                 * were attempted.
                 */
            } else {
                /*
                 * The failed statements can be identified by having
                 * updateCounts[i] == Statement.EXECUTE_FAILED
                 */
            }

            // Presumably you want to:
            dbConnection.commit();

            // Maybe you want to:
            dbCount = 0;  
            prpStmt.clearBatch();
            // Otherwise you need to do some other kind of cleanup / retry
        }

        /*
         * no need to catch any other exception, including SQLException, in
         * this scope, as it's unlikely that the overall bulk insertion can be
         * continued after such an exception.
         */
    }  
}
```

> If the batch fails, is it possible for me to do some sort of loop on the prepared statement, executing each query one by one, and in that way I can figure out the line that failed, and log only that line?

You can determine the statement or statements that failed as shown above.  That will allow you to log the failures.  You cannot remove interrogate a `Statement` object's current batch, however, or remove lines other than via `clearBatch()`, so if the driver happens to be the kind that stops processing a batch after the first error, then recovering from such a failure  might not be a straightforward as you would like.  The needed information is there, though; it might be easier to use you used an indexed `for` loop to iterate over your list instead of an enhanced `for` loop.

> Or is the only way for me to achieve this to keep a separate array of each insert statement, and loop through that if the batch happens to fail?

No, that's not the only way, but I can imagine variations on that that could be implemented cleanly.  With an indexed `for` loop, however, you can recover very cleanly indeed.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for going into such detail. I had completely forgot about clearing the batch on an exception and I'm sure that would've been driving me crazy for a while trying to figure out what's going wrong.